# What is the equivalent in SQLite for "FOR XML PATH('')" in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sqlite

What is the equivalent in SQLite for "FOR XML PATH('')" in SQL SERVER ?

Example data is as below

```
Id   | Value
-----+------
0001 | IN
0001 | ME
0001 | OH
0001 | ON
0002 | AC
0002 | ON
0002 | VI
0002 | ZO
0003 | ME
0003 | OO
0003 | PS
0003 | QA
```

Wanted to get the Data in

```
Id   | Value
-----+------
0001 | IN,ME,OH,ON
0002 | AC,ON,VI,ZO
0003 | ME,OO,PS,QA
```

SQL Server variant that works:

```
 SELECT [id],RIGHT([VALUE],LEN([VALUE])-1) AS [VALUE] FROM (
    SELECT [id],(SELECT ',' + [VALUE] FROM @TEMP 
                  WHERE  [id] = a.[id] FOR xml path('')
                 ) [VALUE]
    FROM   @TEMP a 
    GROUP  BY  [id]
) X
```

I am interested in how to accomplish this in SQLite?

Comment: Er, `SELECT id, group_concat(value) FROM yourtable GROUP BY id ORDER BY id`? Probably very similar with SQL server, too... Edit: `string_agg()` in sql server 2017.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no way to get the sorting of values you seem to expect in your output.  If that order would not be mandatory for you, then consider using `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT Id, GROUP_CONCAT(Value) Value
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Id
ORDER BY Id;
```

Comment: With this query I get value in columns as ";3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0". What would be another query to parse values in [Value] column and to extract only unique values? I am ok to do it with several queries one after the another.

Comment: You should not be seeing this output from my query, assuming the data you posted above be accurate.

Comment: oh sorry, the data is just a simplified example of original data for easier understanding. So assume that output is IN, IN, OH, OH, ME, ME .etc

Comment: I can't help you without having a reproducible problem in front of me.  The above answer is the best I can do using what data I do have.